# Circular button with an icon and a background color

Tags: android, flutter

I want to get this type of button in  a container,

[image: How can I get this]

instead of these icon buttons

[image: Instead of this in flutter]

Comment: Please add some code.

Answer (score 0):

Use BottomAppBar with a FloatingActionButton

Sample here: https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-bottomappbar-navigation-with-fab-8b962bb55013

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`FloatingActionButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html) (FAB). For example:

```
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {
    handlePressed()
  },
  child: SomeIcon(),
  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
);
```

Alternatively, you can do something like:

```
GestureDetector(
  child: Container(
    child: DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      child: SomeIcon(),
    ),
  ),
  onTap: () => handleTap(),
);
```

Although in your case I suppose FAB would make more sense, as it seems from the screenshot that it's on top of `BottomAppBar`.